# Alternate row shading by ID - Conditional Formatting in OpenOffice

Tags: openoffice, conditional-formatting, ruby, openoffice-calc

```
02902982085   4   a   ?  <-- yellow
02902982085   #   1   r  <-- yellow
02902982085   b   $   0  <-- yellow
01395235224   w   z   [  <-- blue
01395235224   a   -   5  <-- blue
10352351342   r   .   r  <-- yellow
10352351342   z   2   -  <-- yellow
10352351342   2   x   0  <-- yellow
10352351342   q   ]   /  <-- yellow
```

I want to alternate light yellow and light blue based on first column. The data is grouped by id, namely the first column. Could have a group of 10+ or just 1. How can this be achieved?

---

(*) The way I am currently doing it is using this ruby script to produce numbers that I can feed into the column and compute =ISEVEN() on them to then do conditional formatting (see image below) on in OpenOffice:

```
f = File.readlines("shading.txt") #<-- I just copy and paste a column from spreadsheet to here

$i = 0
$switch = 0

open('shading_out.txt','a'){|g|
while $i < f.size do
    if f[$i] == f[$i+1]
        g.puts ($switch).to_s + "    " + ($switch).even?.to_s
    else
        if $i == (f.size-1)
            $switch-=1
            g.puts ($switch).to_s + "    " + ($switch).even?.to_s
        else
            g.puts ($switch).to_s + "    " + ($switch).even?.to_s
            $switch+=1
        end
    end
    $i += 1 
end
}
```

Which is just ridiculous... Here is the input (which in reality is me just copying and pasting a column from a spreadsheet into a text file) for above program:

```
02902982085
02902982085
02902982085
01395235224
01395235224
10352351342
10352351342
10352351342
10352351342
```

Which would give this output:

```
0    true
0    true
0    true
1    false
1    false
2    true
2    true
2    true
2    true
```

But I would only produce the numbers and copy the column to the spreadsheet I'm working on, I included the boolean values to help explain my method in (*).

I essentially need a way to get a TRUE FALSE column like this (without using another program and only using OpenOffice formulas/techniques):

```
02902982085   4   a   ?  TRUE  <-- true's would be blue
02902982085   #   1   r  TRUE
02902982085   b   $   0  TRUE
01395235224   w   z   [  FALSE <-- false's would be yellow, i.e., =NOT($E1) would be true for second conditional (see image below)
01395235224   a   -   5  FALSE
10352351342   r   .   r  TRUE
10352351342   z   2   -  TRUE
10352351342   2   x   0  TRUE
10352351342   q   ]   /  TRUE
```

So that I can perform conditional formatting based on the "forumla is" option, in this case column E. This way all TRUE entries would be blue, and a second condition would be =NOT($E1) which would make all FALSE entries yellow. OpenOffice calc has no way, as far as I know, to be able to switch the value of a dummy variable upon a switch in ID, namely the two FALSE instances, which is why I'm using ruby...

---

[image]